# How to install packages from command line on Suse

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, package, suse

What is the Suse version of `apt-get` or `yum`?

How do I install software packages from the command line?

A fairly intense session of googling suggests that it may be `yast` or `yast2`, but no sensible **HOWTO** of listing and installing packages from the command line seems to exist. (maybe I am looking in the wrong place)

If I am an administrator for a remote Suse server, how do I install packages from the command line? (Not using a GUI and preferably installing from a central repo)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

zypper

[Found a tutorial for you](http://web.archive.org/web/20111201053140/http://opensuse-tutorials.com/2008/07/zypper-tips-and-tricks)

[And official documentation](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage)

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Funny how this isnt more widely publicized. But great, thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @edvaldig Please check out [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/220651) about why link-only answers, such as this one, do not help future readers as much as they should. From my own experience, if you don't feel a question is worth putting time in to answer fully, it often means it's a low-quality question.

Comment: @edvaldig Wow! I just realized how old this answer is. You probably already know everything I just told you; and don't worry: some of my early answers suck, too. :-)

Comment: @jpaugh yeah community already edited the original link into the webarchive version of it some years ago :) good point regardless!

Comment: It's clear that The People find this answer useful in all its link-only glory. I certainly did.