# How do I install / enable the PHP phar extension?

Tags: php, linux, shell, composer-php

I am trying to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) on my KnownHost VPS. When I run this command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get this error message:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar
```

How do I install the phar extension? I am running PHP 5.4.22 on my VPS.

Comment: Try this instead: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off`.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, but the flavour of *nix makes a big difference as to what the best way of installing/enabling the phar extension is.

Comment: I think the vps is running centos 6

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am in similar boat at DreamHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved this by getting my host to rebuild PHP with PDO support.

Answer (score 9):

You can modify your php.ini file to get this working. (Some hosts use a phprc file to enable different settings in PHP instead of php.ini. @jerrygarciuh On dreamhost, follow the directions [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214200688-php-ini-overview))

After you have added your php.ini/phprc file, add these lines to the file (just the first line if your server doesn't use Suhosin for security):

```
extension = phar.so 
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```

restart php if you need to (insert php version number with no decimals if different):

```
killall -9 php70.cgi
```

then check to make sure it is working:

```
php -m | grep Phar
```

Finish with the install of composer and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Mind to install phar extension for php.

```
urpmi php-phar
```

or

```
apt-get install php-phar
```

Comment: If I execute `apt-get install php-phar` in suse linux then it just loads forever.

Comment: @Black On suse linux you may prefer zypper command to install, don't you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158838/how-to-install-packages-from-command-line-on-suse

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: For Suse, `zypper install php-phar` works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04. After wasting two hours, I came up with this solution:

1. First install your required PHP version: `sudo apt install php7.2`
2. Install the composer. `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`
3. Check whether the composer is working by simply typing
   `composer`

If the composer is working properly, you are good to go.