# Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar (on windows)

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I'm trying to install composer on my computer windows10, php 7.3.2, i have this  message error for Command-line installation and windows installer  :

```
The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar
```

I enabled Phar in my php file as below but the problem stay:

```
[Phar]
;http://php.net/phar.readonly
phar.readonly = On

;http://php.net/phar.require-hash
phar.require_hash = On

phar.cache_list =
```

when i running php -m i don't see that the extension is activated

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047487/how-do-i-install-enable-the-php-phar-extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install / enable the PHP phar extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047487/how-do-i-install-enable-the-php-phar-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the php.ini files looks like below and with the command PHP -m doesn't show Phar, then you must re-install/ re-configure PHP as the [Phar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php) extension is bundled. After that , running again the php -m command to see if is enabled. Then follow the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) installation guide.

```
[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
;phar.readonly = On
; http://php.net/phar.require-hash
;phar.require_hash = On   
;phar.cache_list =
```